# Different results occur when using tuple and np.array in the minimize function of the scipy.optimize library

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, optimization, scipy

I am performing function minimization, and when using data in the tuple format, everything works correctly but very slowly. I wanted to optimize the code, so I converted everything to np.array, but now I'm getting different values that don't satisfy me, although the speed is excellent. Help me understand what needs to be done to achieve speed similar to np.array but with data that matches the tuple.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import time
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning)

start_time = time.time()

def Bass1(x, P, Q, M):
    return (P * M + (Q - P) * (x)) - (Q / M) * (x ** 2)

def squareMistake1(k: tuple, *sales) -> float:
    p0 = 0
    c0 = sales[0]
    res = 0  # Function value
    for i in range(1, len(sales)):
        p = Bass1(c0, P=k[0], Q=k[1], M=k[2])
        c = c0 + p
        res += (c - sales[i]) ** 2
        p0 = p
        c0 = c
    return res

# Prepare data for minimization
# Initial parameter values
k0 = [0.0008791696672306727, 0.19252826585535315, 3328.9193848309856]
# All parameters are non-negative
kb = ((0, None), (0, None), (0, None))

# The dataset that is needed, ideal values, long execution time
generate = tuple([8.26192344363636, 9.20460066059596, 12.0178164697778, 15.921260267805, 21.2161740066094, 31.420434564131, 38.3904519471421, 52.3307819867071, 62.9113953016839, 85.1161924282732, 104.083879757882, 132.859216030029, 170.682620580279, 220.600045153997, 276.020526299077, 346.465021938078, 440.385091980306, 530.55442135112, 635.49205101167, 705.805860788812, 831.42968828187, 962.227395409379, 1140.31094904253, 1269.52053571083, 1418.17004626655, 1591.2135122193])
# A similar dataset, values are not satisfactory, short execution time
# generate = np.array([8.26192344363636, 9.20460066059596, 12.0178164697778, 15.921260267805, 21.2161740066094, 31.420434564131, 38.3904519471421, 52.3307819867071, 62.9113953016839, 85.1161924282732, 104.083879757882, 132.859216030029, 170.682620580279, 220.600045153997, 276.020526299077, 346.465021938078, 440.385091980306, 530.55442135112, 635.49205101167, 705.805860788812, 831.42968828187, 962.227395409379, 1140.31094904253, 1269.52053571083, 1418.17004626655, 1591.2135122193])

# List of methods used in minimization
method_list = ['Nelder-Mead', 'Powell', 'L-BFGS-B', 'TNC', 'SLSQP', 'trust-constr']

for i in method_list:
    # Minimize the sum of squares
    try:
        res = minimize(squareMistake1, k0, args=generate, method=i, bounds=kb)
    except:
        print(f'Minimization using {i} method failed!')
    k = tuple(res.x)  # Get a tuple of parameters
    print(f'k = {k}')

end_time = time.time()
total_time = end_time - start_time
print(f'Execution time: {total_time} seconds')
```

`np.array` and `pd.DataFrame` produce one result, while `tuple` produces another. I can't figure out what the issue is.

Comment: with in `squareMistake1` check `len(sales)` (and even `sales` itself)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how `args` is processed:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/f990b1d2471748c79bc4260baf8923db0a5248af/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py#L538

If `args` isn't a tuple, it is packed into one. So if `args` is an array, your objective function is expecting to receive many separate arguments, but it gets only one array. `len(sales)` is 1, so the `for` loop doesn't run and the function returns 0.

The [documentation of `minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) specifies that the type of `args` must be `tuple`, so please pass in a tuple for best results.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seems I have no options to speed up my code without sacrificing the best result, as with a tuple?

Comment: You might be able to speed it up by vectorizing `squareMistake` to avoid the `for` loop. That requires a little thinking because `c0` and `p`  update one another each iteration, but it may still be possible. Please check that it is correct, first. `p0` never used, so I'm suspicious. Also, find the minimizer that gives good results and is fastest for your problem and just use that one, no?

Comment: Even without this tuple wrapping (`args=(args,)`), simply using an array instead of a list or tuple does not improve performance.  Iterating on an array is slower than iterating on a list/tuple.  Arrays have to be used in array appropriate ways.

Comment: In my case, I just need to find the most optimal minimizer; they change for different data. In my specific example, the trust-constr minimizer takes a very long time to process, about 1.4 seconds. All others are processed approximately the same in both cases. I assume the whole point is in the processing algorithm of this method. There are small inaccuracies in the formula, correcting which does not change the result.

Comment: `def squareMistake1(k: tuple, *sales) -> float:
    c = sales[0]
    res = 0  # Значение функции
    for i in range(1, len(sales)):
        p = Bass1(c, P=k[0], Q=k[1], M=k[2])
        c = c + p
        res += (c - sales[i])**2
    return res`